# .NET Framework 4 : SMTP command 'AUTH login User: <base64code>' not recognized by ESMTP server

Tags: .net, smtp

i'm testing a console application using a .NET 4.0 Framework Smtp client class with a GTMHS 1.1. (Win32/Ix86) ESMTP Server. 
I'm not IT administrator of the ESMTP server, only a software developer.

During a SMTP client session opened by the .NET application, the SMTP client issues the following SMTP command and thus the following client-server conversation is monitored with Wireshark:

```
C: EHLO <domain>
S: 250 VRFY
S: 250 ETRN
S: 250 8BITMIME
S: 250 PIPELINING
S: 250 AUTH LOGIN PLAIN CRAM-MD5
S: 250 SIZE     
C: AUTH login User: <base64UserCode>
S: 334 VXNlcm5hbWU6
C: Pass: <base64PasswordCode>
S: 334 UGFzc3dvcmQ6
C: MAIL TO : [...]
S: [..] Authentication Failed
```

I think something went wrong during order of SMTP authentication challenge since server asked the base64 Username code after client issued the 'AUTH LOGIN User:' command.  This anomaly cannot be replicated against a Microsoft ESMTP service using the same LOGIN authentication mode and user/password (authentication successful).

Any help appreciated,